# I keep getting a type error when using the reset() function in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I get the type error of:
9: Property 'reset' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
18 |       });
19 |

> 20 |     e.target.reset()
> |              ^^^^^
> 21 |   }

Code:

```
  const handleSchedule = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  
    emailjs.sendForm('Private', 'Private', formRef.current, 'Private')
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
      });
      
    e.target.reset()
```

I tried to give it an any type but thats bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** To fix the type error, you can explicitly cast e.target to the appropriate type, which is likely HTMLFormElement. Here's an example:

```
const handleSchedule = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  emailjs.sendForm('Private', 'Private', formRef.current, 'Private')
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.text);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error.text);
    });

  const formElement = e.target as HTMLFormElement;
  if (formElement && typeof formElement.reset === 'function') {
    formElement.reset();
  }
};
```

By casting e.target as HTMLFormElement, you can access the reset method without a type error. The additional check typeof formElement.reset === 'function' ensures that the reset method exists before calling it.

Please note that it's essential to make sure e.target is indeed an HTML form element in your specific use case.

**Option 2:** Using a reference to reset the form
Another approach is to use a reference to the form element and call the reset method on that reference. This method does not rely on the e.target and can be more reliable in some cases. Here's an example:

```
const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

const handleSchedule = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  emailjs.sendForm('Private', 'Private', formRef.current, 'Private')
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.text);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error.text);
    });

  if (formRef.current) {
    formRef.current.reset();
  }
};
```

```html
// In your JSX
<form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSchedule}>
  {/* Form fields */}
</form>
```